# need to know fieldwise count of records available in a table

Tags: sql

Can u help

I need to know fieldwise count of records available in a table.

Ex: tablename = contactinfo Fields in table: `Name, Dsgn, City`

Need the result as

```
Name = 1000, Dsgn = 990, City = 850
```

Like that

Anoop

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: I doubt count will be same, do you want to know the duplicates?

Answer (score 3):

Standard SQL to give number of distinct non-null values uses

```
SELECT
   COUNT(DISTINCT Name),
   COUNT(DISTINCT Dsgn),
   COUNT(DISTINCT City)
FROM
   contactinfo
```

Just non-null values counting duplicates

```
SELECT
   COUNT(Name),
   COUNT(Dsgn),
   COUNT(City)
FROM
   contactinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean fields where the field is not null, then it is a simple:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM contactinfo WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
```

and repeat :)